# PGFPlots and subfigure and example

Tags: environments, framed

I was plotting some graphs at a separated file, and when I pasted it at another file - the "book" - and now I have an error.
I use the same preamble at both files:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,openany,draft]{book} %draft faz aparecer uns quadrados pretos no fim de alguns mathmode e imagens, então não esquenta se aparecer

\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\usepackage[a4paper,includemp,includefoot, twoside=true inner=1.25in, outer=0.75in]{geometry} %top=2.5cm,bottom=3cm,left=2.5cm,right=3.5cm %ver as margens e coisa  - http://texdoc.net/texmf-dist/doc/latex/geometry/geometry.pdf
\usepackage{marginnote} % tem que rodar duas vezes para ficar direito. A contagem de páginas é diferente da do próprio LaTeX. TEM QUE VER A GEOMETRIA PARA USAR AS MARGIN NOTES.
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\usepackage[table, xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{graphics}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usetikzlibrary{intersections}
    \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc,matrix}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\usepackage[colorlinks=false]{hyperref}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[scaled]{berasans}
\usepackage[super, square]{natbib}
\usepackage{comment}
\usepackage{polynom}
\usepackage{framed}

\newtheorem{teo}{Teorema}[chapter]
\newtheorem{post}{Postulado}[part]
\newtheorem*{lema}{Lema}
\theoremstyle{definition} \newtheorem*{df}{Definição}
\newtheorem*{prop}{Propriedade}

\newcounter{examplecounter}
\newenvironment{exemplo}{\begin{framed}\noindent \refstepcounter{examplecounter} {\textbf{Exemplo \arabic{examplecounter}.}} }{\end{framed}}

\newenvironment{note}{\par \vspace{10pt} \textsc{Versão Humana}\\ \begin{small}}{\\ \noindent\hrule \vspace{10pt} \end{small}}

%%%%%%      TRIGONOMETRICAS - as que precisam e as que não precisam também      %%%%%%
\providecommand{\sin}{} \renewcommand{\sin}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sen}}
\providecommand{\cos}{} \renewcommand{\cos}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{cos}}
\providecommand{\tan}{} \renewcommand{\tan}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{tg}}
\providecommand{\sec}{} \renewcommand{\sec}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{sec}}
\providecommand{\csc}{} \renewcommand{\csc}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{csc}}
\providecommand{\cot}{} \renewcommand{\cot}{\hspace{2pt}\mathrm{cotg}}

\bibliographystyle{docs/plainnapt}

\captionsetup[table]{skip=10pt}
```

And the new code is :

```
\begin{exemplo}
%text
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2,2},
        ytick = {-2,2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:2, dashed, name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:2, dashed, name path=B] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=lime!60!white] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$x^2+y^2<4$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
          \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2},
        ytick = {2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:2, name path=A] {x+2}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:1, color=olive!60!white,  name path=B] {3}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=olive!60!white] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$x+2 \le y$}
    \end{subfigure}
\\
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
      \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2,2},
        ytick = {-2,2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:2, color=olive!60!white, name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:2, color=lime, name path=B] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
       \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:-2,  name path=C] {x+2}; 
       \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:5,  name path=C_1] {x+2}; 
        \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:1, color=white, name path=D] {3};
        \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:3, dashed, name path=E] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:3, dashed, name path=F] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=lime!60!white] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
   \addplot[gray, color=olive!60!white] fill between[of=C and D, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$R \cup S$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad 
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2,2},
        ytick = {-2,2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:0, dashed, name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
       \addplot[samples=100, domain=-3:4, thin, dashed, name path=E] {x+2};
       \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:0, name path=B] {x+2}; 
         \addplot[samples=100, domain=0:2, dashed, name path=C] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:2, dashed, name path=D] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=lime!60!white] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$R \cap S$}
    \end{subfigure}
 \\
     \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
   \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2,2},
        ytick = {-2,2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain= -5:0, white, name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)};
       \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:0, dashed, name path=B] {x+2}; 
         \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:5, dashed, name path=C] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:5, dashed, name path=D] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=lime!60!white] fill between[of=C and D, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
       \addplot[gray, color=white] fill between[of=B and A, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$R - S$}
    \end{subfigure}
    \qquad
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\textwidth}
    \centering
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
        unit vector ratio* = 1 1 1,
        axis lines = middle,
        xtick = {-2,2},
        ytick = {-2,2},
        xmin = -3,
        xmax = 3,
        ymin = -3,
        ymax = 3, 
        xlabel = $x$,
        ylabel = $y$
      ]  
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-2:0,  name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)};
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:5, dashed, name path=A] {sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:5, dashed, name path=B] {-sqrt(-x^2+4)}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:5, dashed, name path=C] {x+2}; 
      \addplot[samples=100, domain=-5:1, color=lime!60!white,  name path=D] {3}; 
      \path[name path=xaxis] (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmin}, -3) -- (\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/xmax},3);
      \addplot[gray, color=olive!60!white] fill between[of=C and D, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
   \addplot[gray, white] fill between[of=A and B, soft clip={domain=-3:3}];
  \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}
    \caption{$S - R$}
    \end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
%text
\end{exemplo}
```

But I discovered the problem is with the "exemplo"'s environment.

Anyone knows how to help?

**Edit**

Here a "real" MWE:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{framed}
    \newcounter{examplecounter}
    \newenvironment{exemplo}{%
        \begin{framed}%
            \noindent
            \refstepcounter{examplecounter}
            {\textbf{Exemplo \arabic{examplecounter}.}}
        }{\end{framed}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{exemplo}
        \begin{figure}
        \end{figure}
    \end{exemplo}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The basic problem is that you can't use a `figure` environment within a `framed` environment (hidden in your `exemplo` env.). In fact, this doesn't make much sense anyway: `figure` is a float, meant to float around to a suitable place, in particular since it takes a whole page in your case. So place the figure outside of the `exemplo` environment, and replace the `H` parameter by `htp`.  If you absolutely want to have the figure within the `exemplo` environment and don't care for lots of white space before, remove `figure` and use the `caption` and `subfig` packages to have still captions.